# The integral of a small-o function is small-o

Tags: real-analysis, frechet-derivative

In the question on [Frechet derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197596/frechet-derivative) it is used that if $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function s.t. $g(x) \in o(x)$, i.e. if $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|g(x)|}{x}=0$ then

$$
\int_0^1g(h(t))dt \in o(h)
$$

where $h\in C[0,1]$, i.e.

$$
\lim_{||h|| \to 0}\frac{ \int_0^1g(h(t))dt}{||h||} = 0
$$

It is straightforward to check that this holds under the supremum norm in $C[0,1]$: if $\epsilon > 0$ is fixed, then if $\delta>0$ is st. $|g(x)| < \epsilon \cdot |x|$ for all $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$ then for any $h \in C[0,1]$ st. $||h||_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|h(t)| < \delta$ we have

$$
 \Big| \int_0^1g(h(t))dt \Big| \leq \int_0^1|g(h(t))|dt 
\leq \int_0^1\epsilon|h(t)|dt \leq \epsilon ||h||_{\infty}
$$

and thus for any $h\in C[0,1]$ with $||h||_{\infty}<\delta$ we have

$$
\frac{ |\int_0^1g(h(t))dt|}{||h||} \leq \frac{\epsilon ||h||}{||h||} = \epsilon.
$$

My question is if it is possible to extend this result to the case where we use the following norm on $C[0,1]$:

$||h|| = \Big(\int |h(t)|^2 dt \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I have tried to decompose the integral by

\begin{align}
\Big| \int_0^1g(h(t))dt \Big| &\leq \Big| \int_{[0,1] \cap (h<\delta) }g(h(t))dt + \int_{[0,1] \cap (h\geq\delta) }g(h(t))dt \Big| \\
&\leq \epsilon\int_0^1h(t)dt + \text{Leb}(\{t\in [0,1] : h(t)\geq \delta\})\cdot C
\end{align}

where $C$ is a bound on the continuous function $g \circ h :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. But it does not quite help with proving that the limit is 0.

Comment: Hello ! I think an absolute value is missing here, it should be $|g(x)| < \epsilon \cdot \lvert x\rvert$ for all $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any requirements on how $g$ behaves near infinity, and if it can be significantly larger than argument, than it can be possible to find $h$ that is large on segment small enough that $\|h\|$ is still small, but $g \circ h$ is significantly larger than $h$ on this segment.

For example, for $g(x) = x^4$, $\epsilon > 0$ and
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\epsilon}, x < \epsilon^3\\ \\
\frac{1 - \frac{x - \epsilon^3}{\epsilon^3}}{\epsilon}, \epsilon^3 \leq x < 2 \epsilon^3\\ \\
0 \end{cases}$$

($1 / \epsilon$ on $[0, \epsilon^3)$, $0$ on $[2\epsilon^3, 1]$ and linear interpolation between)

Then $\|h(x)\| \leq \sqrt{2\epsilon} \to 0$, but $\int_0^1 g(h(x))\, dx > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.